# Issue with taskbar icon on delphi seattle

Tags: vcl, delphi-10-seattle

I have a two delphi VCL applications running on my desktop and one of them is behaving weirdly.

This particular application's taskbar icon doesn't switch to the second monitor's taskbar when I move the application to the second monitor and the other application works just fine.

I don't know what I did to make that happen nor can I reproduce that issue... does anyone have any idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, setting `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True` solves the issue. This is set on the .dpr

The weird part is that on the application that works just fine, this variable isnt set.

If anybody wants to explain why, be my guest... but this solves the issue, sorry to bother you guys.